# PHP define not setting variable value

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP script which I was cleaning up after the code was working. To make code more readable and easy to fix for future, I tried to move all the regularly used variables to constants.

One such variable value was "http://api.io/url/" which I moved to define and assigned to URL_PREFIX

```
define("URL_PREFIX" , "http://api.io/url/");
define("FILE_PREFIX" , "http://api.io/files/");
```

This script worked with the changes. However it started failing suddenly, and on debugging I realized, the place where I am calling URL_PREFIX was assigning the value as "URL_PREFIX" instead of "http://api.io/url/"

```
$apiUrl = URL_PREFIX . "" . $scope;   **[FAILS]**
$apiUrl = "http://api.io/url/" . "" . $scope; **[WORKS]**
```

Am I missing something up here ?

Comment: Where do you define the constants and where do you use them? Make sure its either in the same file or include the definition file in all other scripts that you want to use the constants in.

Comment: PHP will convert `URL_PREFIX` to the string `'URL_PREFIX'` if it's not defined. So that's what's going on. We'd need to know the code path in between your define and the place it's now not defined to know what's going wrong, but a missing `require` or something would normally be the problem.

Comment: make sure define() was called before that

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt they both are defined and used in the same script file.

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko how can i make sure of that

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code? Move the define()-calls to the first lines of your files to make sure of defining them before using them.

Comment: @MattGibson missing require was the first thing i had in mind... but same file

Comment: What happens if you `echo URL_PREFIX` just after the `define`? Does it work? What about if you do it just before the `$apiURL = ...`? Does it still work? If the answer to these two questions is "yes" and "no" respectively, your problem must be in the code you're not showing us.

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt first code block in my question is at top of file.. second code block is part of the file inside a function...

Comment: Place all your defines at the top of your PHP file before you request them

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ got it finally.. i had a control flow that was validating get parameters... and that was just above defines... can yu add that as answer and i will add it marked.. thanks...

Comment: Glad it helped, answered :-)

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ meanwhile i admit.. it was a way silly mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you place any defines at the top of your PHP file, basically make sure you define them before you request them.

Comment: to clarify: at the top of _EVERY_ PHP file that uses that defined constant

Comment: Yes unless this file is used as an include.

Comment: (an include is included in the file)

Answer (score 1):

Set your defines within the very first lines of code (outside of any if's and so on), to make sure they will execute no matter what.

Comment: Thanks... Manuel .. wish i had a way to select your answer as well. Upvoted it though :)

Comment: It only matters that we could help you. :)